# Sql Query to Linq With method syntax

Tags: sql, linq

Can anyone convert this sql query to Linq Method Syntax:

```
select isnull(upl_data, pol_defaultdata),
  upl_userid, upl_countryid, 
  pol_sadmModuleid, pol_name, 
  pol_namelabel,pol_datatype 
from sadmpolicy
left join userpolicy on upl_policyid = pol_id
where pol_scope = 3
```

Comment: Please refer to SO How To Ask - you should show what linq you have tried and explain where is the problem (the is null or the left join or the wheres and such)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var results = from l in sadmpolicyList
              join r in userpolicyList.Where(up=>up.pol_scope =3).ToList() on l.upl_policyid equals r.pol_id into G
from t in G.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
  polData = l.upl_data ?? r.pol_defaultdata,
  upl_userid = l.upl_userid, 
  ...
};
```

(But I am not sure which column is coming from which table, so you might need to adjust the aliases.)

Answer (score -1):

Further to the answer above you could break it out a little and do something along the lines of:

```java
private string prepareSQLCondition(List<paramofsomekind> parameterList, number returnVal) { 

string condition = "SELECT ISNULL (upl_data, pol_defaultdata)";

int count = 1;
// Traverse params
foreach (var param in parameterList)
{
    if (parameterList.Count == count)
    {
        condition += "," + param.value + ",";
    }
    else
    {
       condition += "," + param.value + ",";
    }

    count++;
}

return condition + "WHERE pol_scope =" + returnVal;
}
```

From here you could add more layers of functionality, apply some more control flow, perhaps cater for certain exceptions until you get a fully dynamic solution.

You can then call your method using:
`prepareSQLCondition("param1, param2, param3...`, 3); where the string representation of the params is your `<List>`.

Comment: What part of your answer involves LINQ?  Second, your answer is *ripe* for SQL injection.